# What is the correct way to pass a large number of attributes to a parent constructor if it's possible for an attribute to need a reference to `this`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a general paradigm from which I'd like to create objects. Currently, I have it written in such a way that the parent class builds the paradigm from a configuration object given to it by the subclass. The configuration object defines all of the class' characteristics, and the class is also able to overload any methods that need to be slightly different from one implementation of the paradigm to the next.

This approach is convenient as it allows me to:

- avoid a long list of parameters for the constructor,
- prevent the subclass from needing to define the attributes in any particular order, and
- prevent the subclass from needing to explicitly create instances that the parent constructor can imply from the configuration.

As much as I liked the cleanliness and flexibility of sending this configuration object to `super()`, I've found a glaring limitation to this approach:

I cannot make a reference to `this` until `super` has completed.

```
class Paradigm {
  constructor(config) {
    this.name = config.name;
    this.relationships = config.relationships;
  }
}

class Instance extends Paradigm {
  constructor(name) {
    super({
      name: name,
      relationships: {
        children: {
          foo: new Foo(this) // Error: `this` referenced before `super`
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

class Foo {
  constructor(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }
}
```

<sup>*NOTE: The configuration object is typically significantly larger than this, which is why I'm using it at all.*</sup>

I can imagine there are many ways to approach this, but I'm most interested in what would be the correct way.

- Should I be using functions in place of statements that require a reference to `this` and only execute them when they are needed?
- Should I keep the same approach, but simply replace `super({...})` with `this.build({...})`?
- Should I abandon the idea of the configuration object altogether and instead take a different approach?

Comment: I actually dont really see the benefit of your Paradigma class here.

Comment: The example is minimal as to show the caveat rather than the benefits.

Comment: Why don't you just use them as separate classes if too many changes required for instance your example? Or you could always use the second approach you mentioned but then it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `this` is needed before `super` often suggests that a constructor contains logic that should be moved to separate method.

In some cases some workarounds are possible, as long as they don't cause problems. E.g., a part of configuration that requires `this` can be instantiated later:

```
  constructor(name) {
    const config = {
      name: name,
      relationships: {
        children: {};
      }
    };
    super(config);

    config.relationships.children.foo = new Foo(this);        
  }
```

Of course, this presumes that `relationships` is just stored as a reference and isn't processed on construction.

In more severe cases class hierarchy (`Instance` and `Paradigm`) may be required to be converted to ES5 classes, since ES6 classes can extend regular functions but not vice versa.

Comment: Your first sentence made me realize that I was approaching it incorrectly. I broke the configuration object down into steps so that the `Instance` constructor builds the object rather than the `Paradigm` constructor. The structure is similar to the giant configuration object, but the responsibility for the object's construction is now in the object's constructor rather than the parent class' constructor.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way would be to change your Paradigma to this:

```
class Paradigm {
  constructor(config) {
    Object.assign(this, config(this));
  }
}
```

So that you can do:

```
class Instance extends Paradigm {
   constructor(name) {
     super((context) => ({
       name: name,
       relationships: {
          children: {
             foo: new Foo(context)
           }
       }
    }));
  }
}
```

But actually this is a bad way of solving it...

---

Another way could be to do it the other way round:

```
 const Paradigma = cls =>  class Paradigma extends cls {
   constructor(...args){
     super(config => setTimeout(() => Object.assign(this, config), 1), ...args);
  }
};
```

So you can do:

```
 const Instance = Paradigma(class {
   constructor(build, name){
     build({name});
   }
});

new Instance("Test");
```

Comment: Two things are wrong with this: firstly, Object.assign is assuming that the simplified minimal example given is the extent of what the class would accomplish, ignoring the rest of the question. Secondly, I'm 99% sure this would still give the same error of attempting to reference `this` before `super` is completed.

Comment: That `setTimeout` thingy is really horrible.